# Java: builder pattern, inheritance and generics

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to implement Builder Pattern with inheritance. So I have 4 following classes: one abstract class (ClassA), ClassB, ClassC. TestTest class is used to see how all this works:

```
public abstract class ClassA {

    private String aString;

    public String getaString() {
        return aString;
    }

    public abstract class ClassABuilder<T extends ClassABuilder>{

        public T setaString(String str) {
            ClassA.this.aString = str;
            return (T)this;
        }

        public abstract ClassA build();

    }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA{

    private String bString;

    public String getbString() {
        return bString;
    }

    public class ClassBBuilder<T extends ClassBBuilder> extends ClassA.ClassABuilder<T>{

        public T setbString(String str) {
            ClassB.this.bString = str;
            return (T)this;
        }

        @Override
        public ClassB build(){
            return ClassB.this;
        }
    }
}

public class ClassC extends ClassB{

    private String cString;

    public String getcString() {
        return cString;
    }

    public static ClassCBuilder<ClassCBuilder> newBuilder(){
        return new ClassC().new ClassCBuilder();
    }

    public class ClassCBuilder<T extends ClassCBuilder> extends ClassB.ClassBBuilder<T>{

        public T setcString(String str) {
            ClassC.this.cString = str;
            return (T)this;
        }

        @Override
        public ClassC build(){
            return ClassC.this;
        }
    }
}

public class TestTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ClassC C=ClassC.newBuilder()
                .setaString(null)
                .setbString(null)
                .setcString(null) //LINE XXX
                .build();
    }
}
```

The problem is that at TestTest at LINE XXX I get can't find symbol "setcString". What do I do wrong?

Comment: Note that your builders should be static: otherwise you need an instance of the class you want to build in order to create the builder, in order to create an instance of the class you're trying to build.

Comment: @Andy Turner I didn't add build method to ClassB but see, please, classC - its newBuilder method is static.

Comment: `ClassABuilder<T extends ClassABuilder>` should be `ClassABuilder<T extends ClassABuilder<T>>`, same for other builders.

Comment: yes, but notice you have to create a `ClassC` to create a `ClassCBuilder`. Make the *class* static, and actually build an instance in the build method. As it stands, this isn't the builder pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's track it down along the hierarchy:

First consider this signature:

```
class ClassABuilder<T extends ClassABuilder>
```

When you call `setaString(null)` the returned `T` will be an object that extends `ClassABuilder`. The compiler knows that this is a `ClassBBuilder` and thus will allow you to call `setbString(null)`.

However, since the definition states `T` is required to extend a *raw* `ClassBBuilder` only any information on `ClassBBuilder`'s generic types will be lost. Thus the compiler only knows that `T` is a `ClassBBuilder` but not that it's actually a `ClassCBuilder` which extends `ClassBBuilder<ClassCBuilder>` and hence doesn't know about `setcString()` on the returned type.

As has already been mentioned, using `T extends ClassABuilder<T>` will fix that since now the compiler knows there's another generic type to be passed down the hierarchy.

`newBuilder()` would then have to look like this:

```
public static ClassCBuilder<?> newBuilder(){
    //you have too create a raw type here so you'll have to ignore/suppress/live with the warning
    return (new ClassC().new ClassCBuilder());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @AndyTurner already observed, the problem is that you use raw versions of your builder class types as type parameters.  He did not go into detail, but the upshot is this:

```
ClassC C=ClassC.newBuilder() // yields a ClassCBuilder<ClassCBuilder>
        .setaString(null)    // yields a raw ClassCBuilder (type parameter)
        .setbString(null)    // yields a raw ClassBBuilder (type parameter bound)
        .setcString(null)    // ERROR: no such method on ClassBBuilder
        .build();
```

To fix this with minimal change to your class structure and strategy, you must not only correct the type parameter bounds for your builder classes, as Andy advised ...

```
ClassABuilder<T extends ClassABuilder<T>>
```

... *etc*., but also make a change to `ClassC.newBuilder()`, such as to make it generic:

```
    public static <T extends ClassCBuilder<T>> ClassCBuilder<T> newBuilder() {
        return new ClassC().new ClassCBuilder<T>();
    }
```

With that combination of changes, your code compiles for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post here the test demonstrating builder pattern with deep inheritance.

```
class TypeParamTest {

@Test
void test() {
    Dd dd = Dd.builder()
        .setIntAa(0)
        .setIntBb(1)
        .setIntCc(2)
        .setIntDd(3)
        .build();

    assertEquals(0, dd.intAa);
    assertEquals(1, dd.intBb);
    assertEquals(2, dd.intCc);
    assertEquals(3, dd.intDd);
}

abstract static class Aa {
    int intAa;

    static class AaBuilder<B extends AaBuilder> {
        int intAa;

        Aa build(Aa aa) {
            aa.intAa = intAa;
            return aa;
        }

        B setIntAa(int i) {
            this.intAa = i;
            return (B) this;
        }
    }
}

abstract static class Bb extends Aa {
    int intBb;

    static class BbBuilder<B extends BbBuilder<B>>
        extends AaBuilder<B>
    {
        int intBb;

        Bb build(Bb bb) {
            bb = (Bb) super.build(bb);
            bb.intBb = intBb;
            return bb;
        }

        B setIntBb(int i) {
            this.intBb = i;
            return (B) this;
        }
    }
}

static class Cc extends Bb {
    int intCc;

    static CcBuilder<?> builder() {
        return new CcBuilder<>();
    }

    static class CcBuilder<B extends CcBuilder<B>>
        extends BbBuilder<B>
    {
        int intCc;

        Cc build() {
            return build(new Cc());
        }

        Cc build(Cc cc) {
            cc = (Cc) super.build(cc);
            cc.intCc = intCc;
            return cc;
        }

        B setIntCc(int i) {
            this.intCc = i;
            return (B) this;
        }
    }
}

static class Dd extends Cc {
    int intDd;

    static DdBuilder<?> builder() {
        return new DdBuilder<>();
    }

    static class DdBuilder<B extends DdBuilder<B>>
        extends CcBuilder<B>
    {
        int intDd;

        Dd build() {
            return build(new Dd());
        }

        Dd build(Dd dd) {
            dd = (Dd) super.build(dd);
            dd.intDd = intDd;
            return dd;
        }

        B setIntDd(int i) {
            this.intDd = i;
            return (B) this;
        }
    }
}
}
```