# Java: Builder, Inheritance, Generics Redux

Tags: java, generics

I need to create a set of Builder classes with inheritance through a multi-level hierarchy, whereby the builders need to reside outside of the to-be-built classes as well as in a different package.

Going out from this example: https://onelostlogician.wordpress.com/2016/10/10/inheritance-generics-and-builders/ the code below was created by changing as per the requirements: 1. moving builders to top level, 2. putting builders and to-be-built in different packages and adding setters to the latter, 3. moving static newXYZ() methods into the builders and removing their type parameters to get rid of erasure clash. This would be a suitable model of the desired product.

```
package other;

public abstract class BaseClass {
    protected Integer field1;

    BaseClass () {
    }

    public Integer getField1 () {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1 (Integer field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}

package my;

import other.BaseClass;

public abstract class BaseClassBuilder<T extends BaseClass, BU extends BaseClassBuilder> {
    protected T obj;

    protected BaseClassBuilder (T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    protected final BU getThis () {
        return (BU) this;
    }

    public BU withField1 (Integer field1) {
        obj.setField1(field1);
        return getThis();
    }

    public T build () {
        return this.obj;
    }
}

package other;

import java.util.UUID;

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    protected UUID field2 = null;

    public SubClass () {
    }

    public UUID getField2 () {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2 (UUID field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}

package my;

import java.util.UUID;

import other.SubClass;

public class SubClassBuilder<T extends SubClass, BU extends SubClassBuilder> extends BaseClassBuilder<T, BU> {
    protected SubClassBuilder (T obj) {
        super(obj);
    }

    public BU withField2 (UUID field2) {
        obj.setField2(field2);
        return getThis();
    }

    public T build () {
        return this.obj;
    }

    public static SubClassBuilder neu () {
        return new SubClassBuilder<>(new SubClass());
    }
}

package other;

public class SubSubClass extends SubClass {
    protected String field3 = null;

    public SubSubClass () {
    }

    public String getField3 () {
        return field3;
    }

    public void setField3 (String field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
}

package my;

import other.SubSubClass;

public class SubSubClassBuilder<T extends SubSubClass, BU extends SubSubClassBuilder<T, BU>> extends SubClassBuilder<T, BU> {
    protected SubSubClassBuilder (T obj) {
        super(obj);
    }

    public BU withField3 (String field3) {
        obj.setField3(field3);
        return getThis();
    }

    public T build () {
        return this.obj;
    }

    public static SubSubClassBuilder neu () {
        return new SubSubClassBuilder<>(new SubSubClass());
    }
}
```

Result: SubSubClassBuilder.neu().withField1(..) returns a BaseClassBuilder and withField2(..) a SubClassBuilder, as shown per code completion in Android Studio 3.0.1. Overriding getThis() in each builder did not work, either.

Back to square one, what am I missing?

Edit: Following a hint from [Java: builder pattern, inheritance and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977031/java-builder-pattern-inheritance-and-generics) it was also tried with static (inner) builder classes like so, but to the same effect:

```
    package my;

    import java.util.UUID;

    import other.BaseClass;
    import other.SubClass;
    import other.SubSubClass;

    public class Builders {

        private Builders () {}

        abstract static class BaseClassBuilder<T extends BaseClass, BU extends BaseClassBuilder> {
            protected T obj;

            protected BaseClassBuilder (T obj) {
                this.obj = obj;
            }

            protected final BU getThis () {
                return (BU) this;
            }

            public BU withField1 (Integer field1) {
                obj.setField1(field1);
                return getThis();
            }

            public T build () {
                return this.obj;
            }
        }

        public static class SubClassBuilder<T extends SubClass, BU extends SubClassBuilder> extends BaseClassBuilder<T, BU> {
            protected SubClassBuilder (T obj) {
                super(obj);
            }

            public BU withField2 (UUID field2) {
                obj.setField2(field2);
                return getThis();
            }

            public T build () {
                return this.obj;
            }

            public static SubClassBuilder neu () {
                return new SubClassBuilder<>(new SubClass());
            }
        }

        public static class SubSubClassBuilder<T extends SubSubClass, BU extends SubSubClassBuilder<T, BU>> extends SubClassBuilder<T, BU> {
            protected SubSubClassBuilder (T obj) {
                super(obj);
            }

            public BU withField3 (String field3) {
                obj.setField3(field3);
                return getThis();
            }

            public T build () {
                return this.obj;
            }

            public static SubSubClassBuilder neu () {
                return new SubSubClassBuilder<>(new SubSubClass());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news : it can be done. What makes your approach impossible is that you want the intermediate builder subclasses to both make concrete their own self type and keep it open for extension by subclassing. This proves to be impossible.

To make it work you'll have to, at each level, have an abstract subclass, that adds the necessary methods and allows further extension for subtypes, and a concrete subclass that specifies itself as a specific builder.

[image: Class Diagram]

Here is my adapted implementation :

To start, the base class. What I've changed, is mostly the passing of the self type's class in the constructor.

```
portected abstract class BaseClassBuilder<T extends BaseClass, BU extends BaseClassBuilder<T, BU>> {
    protected T obj;
    private BU self;

    protected BaseClassBuilder (T obj, Class<?> selfType) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.self = (BU) selfType.cast(this);
    }

    final BU getThis () {
        return self;
    }

    public BU withField1 (Integer field1) {
        obj.setField1(field1);
        return getThis();
    }

    public T build () {
        return this.obj;
    }
}
```

Now for the abstract version of the `SubClassBuilder`. This one adds all the methods we need to build instances of `SubClass`, but is still abstract, so it can still serve to be extended.

```
public abstract class AbstractSubClassBuilder<T extends SubClass, BU extends AbstractSubClassBuilder<T, BU>> extends BaseClassBuilder<T, BU> {

    protected AbstractSubClassBuilder(T obj, Class<?> selfType) {
        super(obj, selfType);
    }

    public BU withField2 (UUID field2) {
        obj.setField2(field2);
        return getThis();
    }
}
```

This allows us to make a concrete builder class for `SubClass` instances quite easily :

```
public final class SubClassBuilder extends AbstractSubClassBuilder<SubClass, SubClassBuilder> {

    private SubClassBuilder(SubClass obj) {
        super(obj, SubClassBuilder.class);
    }

    public static SubClassBuilder neu () {
        return new SubClassBuilder(new SubClass());
    }
}
```

The next level works just the same; an abstract class to add the extra builder methods, and to allow further extension, it extends `AbstractSubClassBuilder` :

```
public class AbstractSubSubClassBuilder<T extends SubSubClass, BU extends AbstractSubSubClassBuilder<T, BU>> extends AbstractSubClassBuilder<T, BU> {

   protected AbstractSubSubClassBuilder (T obj, Class<BU> selfType) {
        super(obj, selfType);
    }

    public BU withField3 (String field3) {
        obj.setField3(field3);
        return getThis();
    }
}
```

Making it concrete, takes another class, but now the static factory method doesn't shadow one from its parent (`neu` : are you German?)

```
public class SubSubClassBuilder extends AbstractSubSubClassBuilder<SubSubClass, SubSubClassBuilder> {

    private SubSubClassBuilder(SubSubClass obj) {
        super(obj, SubSubClassBuilder.class);
    }

    public static SubSubClassBuilder neu () {
        return new SubSubClassBuilder(new SubSubClass());
    }
}
```

And now building instances of either class is easy as pie.

```
SubSubClass subSubClass = SubSubClassBuilder.neu()
        .withField2(UUID.randomUUID())
        .withField1(5)
        .withField3("3")
        .build();

SubClass subClass = SubClassBuilder.neu()
        .withField1(66)
        .withField2(UUID.randomUUID())
        .build();
```

(credit to [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) where I've seen this done first)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Implemented it and works like a charm. // Re: are you German? yes; also 'neu' is homophonic with 'new' in English pronunciation hence it seemed a natural choice. // Now I'm still struggling to understand why onelostlogician's example works but not after the changed class organisation. She didn't have intermediate abstract classes. Shadowing the 'neu' functions was not the problem, could have used different names, just easier to use and prettier.